# DataNucleus JDO primary key with enum

Tags: datanucleus

I am attempting to create a primary key for my class using the example at http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_0/jdo/orm/compound_identity.html as a guide. My primary key consists of 3 fields, 2 Strings and 1 enum.

According to http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_0/jdo/types.html, an enum should be able to be part of the primary key, but when the enhancer runs, I get the following:

> Caused by: org.datanucleus.metadata.InvalidPrimaryKeyException: Class "A" has been specified with an object-id class A$PK which has 2 fields, whereas the class has been defined with 3 fields in the primary key. The number of fields in the objectidClass and the number in the primary key must concur.

Can someone clarify as to whether the BEnum enum (just a standard enum with no extra methods) can be used as a field in the primary key? If not, what would be the suggested workaround? If it can, what am I doing wrong?

The class is defined as:

```
PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true", identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, objectIdClass = A.PK.class)
public final class A implements Serializable {
  @PrimaryKey
  private String field1;
  @PrimaryKey
  private BEnum field2;
  @PrimaryKey
  private String field3;

  public static class PK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public String field1;
    public BEnum field2;
    public String field3;

    public PK() {
    }

    public PK( String s ) {
      StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer( s, ":" );
      this.field1 = token.nextToken();
      this.field2 = BEnum.valueOf( token.nextToken() );
      this.field3 = token.nextToken();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return field1 + ":" + field2 + ":" + field3;  
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      int hash = 7;
      hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode( this.field1 );
      hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode( this.field2 );
      hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode( this.field3 );
      return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals( Object obj ) {
      if( obj != null && (obj instanceof PK) ) {
        PK that = (PK)obj;
        return Objects.equals( this.field1, that.field2 ) && this.field2 == that.field2 && Objects.equals( this.field3, that.field3 );
      }
      return false;
    }

  @Persistent
  public String getField1() {
    return field1;
  }

  public void setField1(String field1) {
    this.field1 = field1;
  }
}
```

The enum is simply:

```
public enum BEnum {
  VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3, VALUE4
}
```

Comment: strange, because I have enums in my composite PKs and all work fine, so perhaps there's something you're not telling us ... like the Enum, and the rest of the ...snip...

Comment: I added the snips and enum, but it doesn't seem like there is much to see there. The error is happening during the enhancer stage of the build process. It sees the 3 fields in the main class, but says there are only 2 in the PK.

Comment: and the log says? if it only "sees" 2 then the Enum is not accessible or something.

Comment: Ok, tracked down to the cause of the error, but I still need to figure out a workaround. In the main class, I need DataNucleus to use the setter for field1 because when it gets set, other fields will get set based on the contents of field1. However, that is apparently not acceptable to DataNucleus. If I take the @Persistent annotation off of getField1(), I get no enhancer errors.

Comment: Why would you have any JDO annotation on the getter when you already annotated the field? You annotate one or the other depending on whether you want field or property access for the class. You can't mix and match for fields in the class either

Comment: The reason is as simple as I am new to JDO and DataNucleus. I didn't realize PrimaryKey and Persistent were accomplishing the same thing, at least from a "persist this" kind of thing. Now I know.